# Uploading cookbooks to another server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, cookbook

I downloaded cookbooks from my prod chef server (on site server) with `knife download cookbooks`.

I copied them to a different folder on my machine and tried uploading them to a different chef server (hosted chef server) with `knife upload cookbooks`, but I'm getting a bunch of these errors:

```
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: api.chef.io - SSL_read: cert already in hash table
```

Do I have to disable ssl checking or can I trust certs for both chef servers on my machine?

This seems to happen inconstantly. If I run knife upload cookbooks a bunch of times I'll eventually get all of them uploaded after a bunch of ssl errors.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: My chef workstation is Windows 10

Comment: I've forwarded this over to the Hosted Chef team, it's possible one of their load balancers has a different cert on it or something. You can also reach them directly via support@chef.io

Comment: Ah thanks, wasn't sure if this was a config mistake on my part or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy down from my comment above, this is likely a Hosted Chef issue and not something user-related.